# How to get details of products in a catalog search page?

Tags: magento-1.8

How to get details of products that are displaying in a catalog search page. I want to get Product SKU, Name, Category, Brand etc.

Answer (score 2):

For 
**product name:**

```
$_product->getName();
```

**Sku:**

`$_product->getSku();`

**Category  details:**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $_product->getId());

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
}
```

**Brand Attribute:**

```
$attribute_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Comment: No success unfortunately, I want to get product details in a catalog search page. This code is working fine for view.phtml but not for catalog search page. Thanks

Comment: please show catalogsearch  page code?

Comment: It's result.phtml file which is in the below path. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalogsearch\result.phtml

Comment: as per as concept,Magento does the prodtc direcionly result.phtml it call list.php which is show products

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

**Name**

$this->getName();

**Sku**

$this->getSku();

Answer (score 0):

On the catalogsearch results page, there's a product collection that is loaded in the content block. See the catalogsearch layout:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <label>Quick Search Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
            <action method="setListOrders"/>
            <action method="setListModes"/>
            <action method="setListCollection"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

The product collection is loaded in the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List class in the protected function _getProductCollection. To add additional attributes to the collection, you can either rewrite this block or observe the catalog_block_product_list_collection event (dispatched on line 162 of this block). Either rewrite or event observer requires a custom module.